# Should the alien-languages tag be renamed to fictional-languages?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Considering we just [merged with Fantasy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300/), I think we should rename the [alien-languages tag](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alien-languages) to fictional-languages. It'd describe the category just as well and be more inclusive, allowing for elvish and its ilk.

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let's just merge [alien-languages](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alien-languages) with the existing [languages](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/languages) tag - shorter is better than longer, and the "fictional" is somewhat implied by the fact that this is a Q&A site for fiction.

Comment: This also clears up confusion about fictional languages that became 'real' ones.... Like all of them. :P

Comment: No-one seems to object, so I've done this.  Revert if you disagree!

Comment: your wording is deliciously reminiscent of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10143/can-revert-be-used-as-a-synonym-of-reply :-)

Answer (score 5):

That makes sense. Tags on SE sites are generally more useful when they're inclusive.