# Scifi Stack Exchange is now "Science Fiction & Fantasy"

Tags: discussion, scope

**ANNOUNCEMENT:**

This site has been *officially* renamed **"Science Fiction and Fantasy"**. While both subjects were generally considered on topic, the fantasy genre is now *explicitly* integrated into this site. The FAQ has been updated, the fantasy-related proposals have been redirect to this site, and the logo and name changes will appear shortly.

Comment: Will the url (scifi.stackexchange.com) change to something else or will it remain the same?

Comment: @Borror0: It will remain the same.

Comment: @Robert is there potential to change that if the site makes it through beta? It's not ideal.

Comment: @Robert could the stackscifi twitter account name be updated?

Comment: @Tony Meyer: What name are you suggesting? Ideally it should be less than 8-10 characters, be intuitive and easy to remember, and not obfuscate the subject of the site. Those criteria are preferable to 100% technical accuracy.

Comment: sff.stackexchange.com or sfandf.stackexchange.com? IMO including fantasy is more than technical accuracy.

Comment: @Tony Meyer: This is my *personal* opinion but I don't care for "sfandf" at all. "Sff" has a bit of merit although I prefer the scifi-SE name. That's not really for me to decide, though, so the best way to proceed is to post the request tagged as a [feature-suggestion] and let the community vet the suggestion.

Comment: @Robert ok will do - thanks!