# Add an alias of sff.stackexchange.com

Tags: feature-request

This stack lives at ***SciFi***.stackexchange.com, with an [alias of ***Fantasy***.stackexchange.com](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/316/19561).

The full name of this stack is "Science Fiction & Fantasy", but this is not reflected in either URL.

Therefore, I suggest to make ***SFF***.stackexchange.com an alias as well. This [has been suggested before](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/323/19561), but was never acted upon.

Taking the pros and cons from that suggestion:

#### Pros:

- Includes both sci-fi and fantasy.
- SF&F is a well-established moniker for the genre, along with F&SF (e.g. *The Magazine of Fantasy & Science Fiction* is generally called just F&SF or F&SF mag).
- Short (at least the subdomain is - we're stuck with the lengthy "stackexchange.com").
- It resembles other StackExchange names, like gis, diy, rpg, and dba.
- It doesn't need capitalisation/hyphenation (e.g. sfandf, fandsf, sf-f, f-sf or scifiandfantasy) to be clearly read.

#### Cons:

- It's not immediately clear what "sff" or "fsf" mean to anyone not expecting it to be a genre. (OTOH, most of the traffic comes from Google, where this isn't that important).
- SF (with only one F) is used to refer to ServerFault.

Comment: Note that when this came up before the site was in beta and it was more a discussion about actually renaming the site than adding aliases (but the rename never got momentum, so a single alias was what we got).

Comment: note that [arqade.com](http://arqade.com) redirects to gaming.stackexchange.com - i.e. it's not necessary for any redirect to have '.stackexchange' in it